# c++ vector iterator output display vertically in columns

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to output my strings column-wise using the vector iterator as shown in the attached image.
For now I am just displaying a test case using the names and the cider order after which I want to replicate the same for others. [image: Desired output screenshot]

Below is my current code:

```
// values for controlling format
const int name_width = 15 ;
const int int_width = 7 ;
const int dbl_width = 12 ;
const int num_flds = 7 ;
const std::string sep = " |" ;
auto total_width = name_width*2 + int_width*2 + dbl_width*3 + sep.size() * num_flds ;
const std::string line = sep + std::string( total_width-1, '-' ) + '|' ;

cout<<"How many people ordered? ";
cin>>odrs; // Store number of orders

for(int i=1; i<=odrs; i++){
    cout<<"Enter the name of person #"<<i<<":"<<endl;;
    cin>>names;  // Store names of users

    odrNames.push_back(names);  // Store names as entered as

    cout<<"How many orders of cider did "<<names<<" have? ";
    cout<<endl;
    cin>>odrciderjuice;  // Store Cider order item
    sbCider = odrciderjuice * 5.5;    // Calculate Cider order per price
    odrCider.push_back(odrciderjuice); // Store Cider order item based on entry
    SbCider.push_back(sbCider);      // Store calculated Cider order per price

    cout<<"How many orders of apple juice did "<<names<<" have? ";
    cout<<endl;
    cin>>odrapplejuice;     // Store Juice order item
    sbJuice = odrapplejuice * 4.5;    // Calculate Juice order per price
    odrApple.push_back(odrapplejuice);     // Store Juice order item based on entry
    SbJuice.push_back(sbJuice);      // Store calculated Juice order per price
    cout<<endl;

    total = sbCider + sbJuice;   // Calculate total between Cider and Juice
    GTotal.push_back(total);     // Store total values after calculation
    cout<<endl;
}

for(vector<string>::iterator naming = odrNames.begin(); naming!= odrNames.end(); ++naming)
    cout << sep << std::setw(name_width) << *naming<<"\v";

for(vector<int>::iterator ciderOdr = odrCider.begin(); ciderOdr!= odrCider.end(); ++ciderOdr)
    cout <<*ciderOdr;
```

Comment: Consider storing each order in a struct or class and then store instances of that object in your vector. Once you have that it's much simpler to format each line.

Answer (score 1):

Using iterator is indeed the idiomatic way to browse a collection. Simply, you need a collection of objects, instead of a bunch of unrelated collections!

In addition, you should be more consistent in your names, and only capitalizing a name between a single value and its collection is a future maintenance nightmare...

C++ is an OO language, and OO programming is a way to split a complex program in smaller units (the classes), which are responsable for only one small part of a larger program. This is intended to lead to code that is both simpler to test and to maintain.

Here the `Order` class could contain:

- one string for the client name
- 2 integers for the number of cider and of juice
- optionally methods to compute the detailed and total prices

As your formatting is not trivial, I would use an alternate class to handle it. That class would contain:

- a reference to a `vector<Order>`
- a reference to an `ostream`
- static elements for the format details
- methods to display the header line, an horizontal dash line, an order line, and the total and average lines.

The main would then simply contain code to load the orders.

Code could be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

struct Order {
    static constexpr double ciderPrice = 5.5;
    static constexpr double juicePrice = 4.5;
    std::string name;
    int cider;
    int juice;

    double sbCider() const {
        return cider * ciderPrice;
    }
    double sbJuice() const {
        return juice * juicePrice;
    }
    double total() const {
        return sbCider() + sbJuice();
    }
};

class Bill {
    // values for controlling format
    static const int name_width = 10 ;
    static const int int_width = 6 ;
    static const int dbl_width = 17 ;

    const std::vector<Order>& orders;
    std::ostream& out;

    ...

public:
    Bill(const std::vector<Order>& orders, std::ostream& out):orders(orders),out(out) { }
    Bill& show_line() {
        ...
        return *this;
    }
    Bill& show_header() {
        ...
        return *this;
    }
    Bill& show_order(const Order &order) {
        ...
        return *this
    }
    Bill& show_total() {
        return *this
    }
    Bill &show_average() {
        ...
        return *this;
    }
    Bill& show() {
        ...
        show_header().show_line();
        for (const Order& order: orders) {
            show_order(order);
        }
        return show_line().show_total().show_average().show_line();
    }
};
int main() {
Order order;
vector<Order> orders;

int odrs;

cout<<"How many people ordered? ";
cin>>odrs; // Store number of orders

for(int i=1; i<=odrs; i++){
    cout<<"Enter the name of person #"<<i<<":"<<endl;;
    cin>>order.name;  // Store names of users

    cout<<"How many orders of cider did "<<order.name<<" have? "<<endl;
    cin>>order.cider;  // Store Cider order item

    cout<<"How many orders of apple juice did "<<order.name<<" have? "<<endl;
    cin>>order.juice;     // Store Juice order item
    orders.push_back(order);
}

Bill bill(orders, std::cout);
bill.show();
return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Many thanks Serge for the input. However, i am getting some errors when i try to run your code: 
1. the Contructor Bill gives the error Expected member name or ';' after declaration
2. No matching constructor for initialization of Bill

Comment: @Nii1: the ... are markers that the `Bill` class is not complete. This code only intends to show you how you could change the general design, but it is not working code.